# implicit functions

Tags: calculus

Define $F$ as
$$F(x,y,u,v) = x^3e^{uv} + vy^2\sin{\left(y^3\right)}$$
where $u(x,y) = x^2y$ and $v(x,y) = xy^3$.

Define $f(x,y) = F(x,y,u(x,y),v(x,y)$.

Determine $\dfrac{\partial F}{\partial x}$ and $\dfrac{\partial f}{\partial x}$.

How to do this for $F$ and $f$ respectively? Aren't $F$ and $f$ the same? I'm confused. Thanks

Comment: What you are looking for is the *multivariable chain rule*.

Comment: chain rule tutorials doesn't have this situation.

Comment: What you have is $f$ is a "function" of $F$ I.e. $f(F)=F$.

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Ok, your question was edited.

Try to look the "path" of the variables of your function.

By example, here we have:

$~F \to u, v, x, y~$ WHERE $~u~$ and $~v~$ depends of $~x~$ and $~y~$.

If you define a new function, $~f~$, which has $~x,~y~$ as variables, it remains only two variables (in fact).

By example, if you want to determine the partial derivative of $~f~$, just "follow" the path to "$~x~$".

$~f \to x ,~ y , ~u(x,y),~ v(x,y),~$ so you have to derivate everywhere $~x~$ is.

So, you'll have:

$$~\frac{df}{dx} + \frac{df}{du}\cdot \frac{du}{dx} + \frac{df}{dv}\cdot\frac{dv}{dx}~$$ where $~d~$ is the partial derivative.

I might be not clear as English isn't my mother-tongue, but I suggest you this link:

http://www.math.hmc.edu/calculus/tutorials/multichainrule/

Comment: is df/dx + (df/du)(du/dx) + (df/dv)(dv/dx)  for f? how about F

Comment: for me it's the same

Comment: no , you're wrong

Comment: @Frank Xu If you think this solution is wrong, can you describe why you think it is wrong?

Comment: When I said "same" it doesn't mean equals.